# Nested If Statements SSRS Expression

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

Building a report and changing colour based on some variables. If it is a Break Semester then make the colour "Gainsboro". If attendance is less than 0.4 as well as not being null then make the colour "#ffc7ce"

I'm totally confused as to why this code won't run, it seems simple enough.

```
=IIF(fields!Break_Semester <> "Break Semester"
    ,IIF(len(Fields!Attendance.Value) <> 0 and Fields!Attendance.Value < 0.4 
        ,"#ffc7ce"
    ,"Gainsboro")
,"Gainsboro")
```

The code works when running this:

```
=IIF(len(Fields!Attendance.Value) <> 0 and Fields!Attendance.Value < 0.4 
    ,"#ffc7ce"
,"Gainsboro")
```

So I'm not sure why the nesting screws it up.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you've simply misidentified the `Break_Semester` field.  Make sure to capitalize the `Fields` portion and you need to add `.Value`.  So it should be

```
=IIF(Fields!Break_Semester.Value <> "Break Semester"
,IIF(len(Fields!Attendance.Value) <> 0 and Fields!Attendance.Value < 0.4 
    ,"#ffc7ce"
    ,"Gainsboro")
,"Gainsboro")
```

Could be nice to add parenthesis around your conditional statements as well, but that's just a personal preference to keep things cleaner.

Comment: Thank you! I feel like I'm back in high school, silly question. I ended up not needing a nested IF and just used `=IIF(len(Fields!Attendance.Value) <> 0 and Fields!Attendance.Value < 0.4 and Fields!Break_Semester.Value <> "Break Semester"
 ,"#ffc7ce"
,"Gainsboro")`